# Error while building Android project with using Geotools (solved)

Tags: java, gradle, geotools

I'm working on an android project and need to use the Geotools library.
Building the project after adding the library is incorrect.

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'

Adding a repository to Gradle:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/" }  // <---
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    gradlePluginPortal()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

Adding a dependency to Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.geotools:gt-main:28.0'  // <---
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
}
```

I get an error during the build:

```
> Task :android:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED
Execution failed for task ':android:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > 2 files found with path 'plugin.xml' from inputs:
      - C:\gradle\caches\transforms-3\4ee35d2fa6e19aaa21a107f9d19d12b8\transformed\jetified-org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi-2.15.0.jar
      - C:\gradle\caches\transforms-3\c4ca9df1db430b1e56c1959084f034a1\transformed\jetified-org.eclipse.emf.ecore-2.15.0.jar
     Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
     https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
     for more information
```

Downgrading the library version does not help.
Please, assist in the assembly, I have been sitting for the third night

**Update**
I will answer for myself:
changed the repository to

https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/geotools-releases/

adding a block also helped:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        exclude 'plugin.xml'
        exclude 'about.ini'
        exclude 'about.mappings'
        exclude 'modeling32.png'
        exclude 'about.properties'
        exclude 'plugin.properties'
    }
}
```

Might be useful to someone :)

Comment: P.s. thought to add PackagingOptions for file plugin.xml, but did not understand in which block it should have been added, and I don't know if it will help

Comment: I don't think GeoTools works on Android.

Comment: @IanTurton, I tried to connect to the project without building in Gradle, through JUnit, and the library functionality worked fine (that is, Gradle normally sees the library itself, downloads it and uses it).
The problem is only during the assembly of the project itself in the mergeDebugJavaResource/mergeJavaResource block, and it is not clear which way to fix

Comment: P.s. except that the idea arose to add the repository not to the general project, but to the core (an internal module that does not interact with android, but performs utilitarian functions, and there you need to perform the necessary actions with the library)